# listfunction doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++, oop, vector, switch-statement

I'm trying to list a vector of ingredients.

the class Ingredient only has 2 members and 2 member functions (except for constructor). it holds a name and a category and it has the functions "getName" that returns the name and "getCategory" that returns category. these ingredients are then stored in a vector - cabinet.

here is the code that SHOULD list the content of cabinet:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cabinet.size(); i++)
{
   cout << cabinet[i].getName();
   switch(cabinet[i].getCategory())
   {
      case 1: cout << "Alcohol" << endl;
              break;
      case 2: cout << "Liqueur" << endl;
              break;
      case 3: cout << "Brew" << endl;
              break;
      case 4: cout << "Non alcohol" << endl;
              break;
      case 5: cout << "Wine" << endl;
              break;
   }
}
```

what I get:

```
[first ingredient][second ingredient][thrid ingredient]...etc
```

so, why doesn't my switch-statement work?

Comment: What is the symptom for it "not working"?

Comment: Need to see the rest of the code. Nothing obviously wrong with the code you've posted. Also your explanation of what is wrong isn't very clear. Please post exactly what you get and exactly what you expected.

Comment: Since getCategory does not deliver an integer between 1 and 5? Add `default: cout << cabinet[i].getCategory();` at the end of the switch to find out what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help! I tried adding `default: cout << cabinet[i].getCategory();` and found that I accidently stored it as a char. fixed the add-function and now it works.
Thanks again for the help!